# How do I say "The things I do"

Tags: grammar

I've been working a bit on writing lately, and I'm trying to figure out how best to translate the classic english statement "The things I do". For example, I would like to say 
"Sometimes the things I do are actually good for my own future".

Could I say 有时候我喜欢做的东西对我自己的未来很好。

Do people ever say "我做的东西“ or 做的事 ？  or is this a poor translation for what I'd like to say?

Comment: 有的时候我做的事情对我自己的未来有好处

Answer (score 3, accepted):

有时做我想做的事其实对自己的前途有利 would perhaps do. Although you could say "做的东西", it is probably far more common to say "做的事".

Comment: Do I need 其实？ In english this sentence would make just as much sense without "actually"

Comment: Also why is 有利  better than simply 好？

Comment: Cuz "good" in this context means "beneficial", which is 有利.

Answer (score 1):

> 有时候我喜欢做的东西对我自己的未来很好。

It's probably better to use “事” as a general reference to "things" as “东西” will make “做” mean like "make", and you're missing "**actually**".

I'd say

> 有时候我喜欢做的事 **其实** 对我自己的未来很好。

Answer (score 1):

The translation as suggested by the OP is not wrong (in that any chinese reading it should be able to understand what he is trying to say) but definitely sounds like a translation. It's "unnatural".

It is not necessary to specifically say "做的东西" or "做的事". It is better to simply say "我所做的". These include all the things that I do - it makes no differentiation between "东西" (a physical item) or "事" (a course of action).

My take "我所做的偶也利于我的未来". Here "偶" means "sometimes". "也" tends to reinforce the fact that "not always" and "not all the things I do" are beneficial "利" to "于" my own future "我的未来", but they do sometimes. "也" also echoes "actually" in the original sentence.